# Uploading similar applications to App Store from same developer account

Tags: ios, app-store

We have a couple of apps  which allows a user to search for all available properties in specific area, then we have several apps for several different companies that allows the user to search for property that only that company is marketing - i.e you could have apps for Company 1, Company 2, and Company 3 etc which all look the same except for the branding but each one only return results of properties that they are marketing. Will apple allow us to publish these applications through a single apple developer account?
Please guide me if it violates the apple terms and conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can release them from single account as long as they have different names and distributed with unique and different app ids. The apple won't reject the apps on these grounds. I've seen people selling such solutions/templates to clients and they're up for sale from same developer account.